# React useState to change icon using fontawesome not updating

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, use-state

I'm trying to change the icon by clicking the icon. The value of isOpen changes on the console, but the icon doesn't change.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

<header className="w-full h-20 shadow-sm">
    <div className="h-full sm:mx-6 md:mx-12 lg:mx-24 xl:mx-48 px-4 xl:px-0">
      <nav className="h-full flex justify-between items-center text-lg">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <p className="font-bold text-blue z-10">Shaddam</p>
          <figure className="-ml-4 z-0">
            <img src={BrandIconBg} alt="Blob" />
          </figure>
        </div>
        <span
          className="text-blue text-2xl cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
        >
          <i className={!isOpen ? "fas fa-bars" : "fas fa-times"}></i>
        </span>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Can you send a codesandbox please. Because the issue definitely isn't in the code part you sent.

Comment: Is better to change the code, depends on "isOpen" state, then to render the appropriate icon with specific className

Comment: here codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-1imcz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: idk why on codesandbox is working but on local development isnt working

Comment: Yeah. Technically you don't have any issues there so it should work.

Comment: As you know now that the logic there isn't wrong, I think you need to look for the problem somewhere in your project. You can also try clean-installing your packages and running this again.

Comment: Could you please add your whole component? It seems like you have another issue effecting this problem.

Comment: @shadowman_93 https://github.com/shaddamalghafiqih/PersonalWebsite here my github repo

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your logic a bit. The reason behind this issue, icon is not showing up because **your local development environment or browser** is not rendering new icon when your changes takes effect.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

<header className="w-full h-20 shadow-sm">
    <div className="h-full sm:mx-6 md:mx-12 lg:mx-24 xl:mx-48 px-4 xl:px-0">
      <nav className="h-full flex justify-between items-center text-lg">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <p className="font-bold text-blue z-10">Shaddam</p>
          <figure className="-ml-4 z-0">
            <img src={BrandIconBg} alt="Blob" />
          </figure>
        </div>
        <span
          className="text-blue text-2xl cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
        >
          {isOpen ? 
          <i className="fas fa-bars"></i> :
          <i className="fas fa-times"></i>}
        </span>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

**[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fontawesome-5-playground-forked-wtz9e) is working playground example.**

Comment: its still not working, here my repo https://github.com/shaddamalghafiqih/PersonalWebsite maybe u need it, this code from src/parts/Header.js

Comment: Its working. Maybe you have another issue related with it. Here is example: https://codesandbox.io/s/fontawesome-5-playground-forked-wtz9e

Answer (score -1):

fixed, its because i use fontawesome cdn instead of using npm package, when i change to npm package for fontawesome its working

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation